# Join to same table Prisma

Tags: node.js, prisma

I have this query on MySQL

```
select m2.* from MS.Member as m1 INNER JOIN
MS.Member as m2 ON m1.ChannelId = m2.ChannelId and
m2.UserId not in (18)
where m1.UserId=18;
```

I want create a Prisma Query with this model

```
export type Member = {
  Id: number
  UserId: number
  ChannelId: number
  Status: string
  CreatedOn: Date
  CreatedBy: string
  ModifiedOn: Date | null
  ModifiedBy: string | null
}
```

How I can do that? I'm using nodejs and typescript

Comment: what have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way

`let filterDB: IWhereFilter<Prisma.UserWhereInput>;`

`filterDB = { NOT: { Id: userId }, Member: { none: {} } };`

`const queryFilter: IDbQueryFilter<TModel> = <IDbQueryFilter<TModel>>{orderBy, skip, take, select };`

`if (filter != undefined) { queryFilter.where = { ...filter };}`

`const modelName: "user";`
`return this.client[modelName].findMany(queryFilter);`